Microfrontends - Module Federation - React - Vite - preact/signals-react - Not Working from remote
I'm starting a project from scratch.
I would like to work with the signals feature from preact.
Right now i can make **signals ** work locally on my host, but when i import a component from a **remote module ** that uses signals it breaks giving me this error:

This is the remote button being imported:

Here i'm importing the button from remote:

This is the vite.config for host:

This is the vite.config for remote-1:

I would really appreciate some help here, i'm out of ideas of what approach to take to solve this.
Thanks!

I used useState hook instead of signals in remote Button and it works ok, i can import it on host and execute setState without trouble.

